# Using K&R-style C functions in C++ code

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I'm trying to use [oncrpc-windows](http://sourceforge.net/projects/oncrpc-windows/) project in my VC++ project in VS2010. The oncrpc exports functions in [svc.h](http://oncrpc-windows.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/oncrpc-windows/win32/include/rpc/svc.h?revision=1&content-type=text/plain) files without any arguments, but in fact the functions have arguments. For example, the header file exports

```
#define DllExport   __declspec( dllexport ) 
...
DllExport SVCXPRT *svcudp_create();
```

but [the implementation file](http://oncrpc-windows.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/oncrpc-windows/win32/librpc/Svc_udp.c?revision=1&content-type=text/plain) contains

```
SVCXPRT * svcudp_create(sock)
    int sock;
{

    return(svcudp_bufcreate(sock, UDPMSGSIZE, UDPMSGSIZE));
}
```

If I try to create C file which uses exported functions, then everything is OK, the code is compiled successfully. The problem is I can't use the exported function in my CPP code, the compiler stops with the following message

> error C2660: 'svcudp_create' : function does not take 1 arguments

I tried to use `extern "C"`, however it didn't help. I'm wondering how can I use the exported functions in my VC++ project? Is it really need to write own header files with correct signatures?

Comment: `DllExport SVCXPRT *svcudp_create();` the header clearly shows that it doesn't take 1 argument. fix the header to match he function declaration. `DllExport SVCXPRT *svcudp_create(int );`

Comment: @stardust_ It's a C header, so the declaration says nothing about the arguments the function takes. Of course the header should contain a prototype and not just a declaration anyway.

Comment: @DanielFischer: If you compile it with a C++ compiler, it's a C++ header. `int foo()` means `int foo(void)` even if `foo` is `extern "C"`.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think @DanielFischer is saying that in C you can _declare_ a function without specifying its parameters. You specify parameters in function's _definition_ later and can work with them inside the function. Basically, the problem is that C++ compiler treats, say, `int foo();` as `foo returns int and takes no arguments`, while C treats it as `foo returns int and takes some non-va_arg parameters`.

Comment: @PetrBudnik Yes, though n.m.'s point is very valid, if you include it in a C++ file, the header will change its meaning even wrapped in `extern "C"`.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, I see now that n.m. was just elaborating on your comment by saying: even if you wrap it in `extern "C"`, it's not going to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to compile any .c files which use K&R style syntax to object files before you compile your .cc or .cpp files.  This should be done in a MakeFile.

Example:

```
PNAME = "ProjectName"
PROGRAM_FILES = program.cpp program.h

svc.o: svc.c svc.h
    gcc -c $< -o $@
program.o: $(PROGRAM_FILES)
    gcc -c $< -o $@
all: svc.o program.o
    gcc $< -o $(PNAME)
clean:
    -rm -f *.o $(PNAME)
```